# RegOpenKeyEx returned 2

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I have a problem with RegOpenKeyEx() function.

```
lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, lpSubKeyName, 0, KEY_READ, &hkMon);
```

Function return error code 2 (file not found), but this key exist in registry.
I try this on Windows 7 64-bit and Windows Xp 32bit.

Comment: The key does not exist. It's that simple.

Comment: What is the line of code that gives `lpSubKeyName` its value?

Comment: If this is a 32-bit program, the key in question might exist in the 64-bit registry but not the 32-bit registry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When working with the registry you have to be aware of UAC [registry virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx) (VirtualStore redirection for compatibility) and WOW64 (32/64 bit separation and [registry redirection/reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx)). Because of these features you sometimes end up in a different place in the registry and it will not match up with what you see in Regedit.

In cases like these the best thing to do is to use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) so you can see which key you are really accessing...

Comment: Also always triple check for user error, like when I just spent an hour to figure out that I was including the subkey in the main key, after convincing myself that it was a folder with a {default} value.